Eliminating nullity for enhanced non-singularity
If we have an
$n\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries either $0$ or $1$, where all diagonal entries are $0$ and the rank is $k<n$, can we reach full rank by changing exactly $n-k$ zero off-diagonal entries to one when $n\ge2$?

Obviously not when $n=1$, $k=0$. For small $n\ge 2$ (at least $n=3,4,5$), I imagine that one can check all cases: did you try? At least it is always true (for all $n$) when $k=1$.

@YCor, excluding the trivial scenario you highlighted, it seems that  the assertion holds true for $n\leq 7$.

Note on the edit: it's true for the zero matrix when $n\ge 2$ (and this is useful to deal with the case $k=1$). So I'd just assume $n\ge 2$ (or $(n,k)\neq (1,0)$).
